# Should I turn off PC with Windows after installing new software?

Tags: windows, shutdown

I was taught that you need to turn off /shutdown the computer after installing a new program or 
make some changes in the system settings. I did it because I thought that when the of a computer freeze/crash( when I have to restart system) the program or changes would not be saved. is it worth doing or it just a stupid habit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the specific software you're installing requires a restart, it will most likely request to do so, and it might fail to launch before the restart - this is usually related to changes to the registry and/or environment variables (it can be circumvented sometimes, but it's often the easiest thing to just restart). Otherwise, nothing stops you from using the software right away if it works.

P.S. Some installers ask for a restart even if one isn't really required - supposedly just "for good measure", or, if using a ready-made installer that normally asks for a restart and the developer hasn't disabled that.

Comment: I have also found that Adobe and Office updates may interact until restarted as well. Just another reason to restart to ensure all changes get made

Comment: One more question. What happend if I just shutdown PC and then turn on instead restart it when any program requests? It is any difference?

Comment: From the point of view of the OS, a restart is the same thing as a shutdown and then power on (except for when there's features like Fast Startup enabled - these are similar to hibernation and then restoring the session).

Comment: If you just shut off the PC, any pending updates will happen when you start up. But that should not cause an issue. It is just easier to restart and be sure all is done

Answer (score 0):

I have done this both ways and have determined over time that it is better to restart, allow updates to complete and then (if desired) turn the machine off.

If you turn the machine off first, there may be a big update cycle that will occur before you use the machine. Restart is better